# finding specific combination of chars one after another in 2d array java

Tags: java, arrays, char

I would like to find combination of char letters in big 2d array made of random letters from a to z.
The combination of letters would be first as follows : letter 'a', 2nd letter directly after this one 'l' and 3rd letter after that would be again 'a'.
If combinaton of those letters was found, then i would like to increase the number that it occured by 1. So in the end i would know exactly how many times those specific letters were randomly generated next to each other in this order.

```
    char[][] x = new char[1000][1100]; 
    int amountofAla = 0;    

    for (int i=0; i<x.length; i++) {
        for (int r=0; r<x[i].length; r++)  {
            x[i][r] = abc.charAt((int)(Math.random()*26)) ;
        }
    } // my 2d tab with random generated letters was made here

    // below is my attempt to find combination of letters 'a'+'l'+'a'
    for (int i=0; i<x.length; i++) 
    {
    for (int w=0; w<x.length; w++) 
        {
        if (x[i][w] ==('a') && x[i][w+1] == 'l' && x[i][w+2] == 'a')
            amountofAla = amountofAla+1 ;
        else;
            }
    }
    System.out.println("occurance= " + amountofAla);
```

My attempt of finding letters in this order is giving wrong number. I printed the tab and searched for ala manualy, and number is always wrong.

```
    // print array for refference 
    for (int i=0; i<x.length; i++) {
        for (int r=0; r<x[i].length; r++) {
            System.out.print( x [i] [r]);
        } System.out.println( );
    }
```

Thank You in advance for any thoughts about given issue.

Comment: Hint: dont create/test code like this. Instead: first write a unit test that defines a array with **known** content. Then use that array as input to your actual code that is supposed to find whatever you intend to find. Trying to debug a complicated algorithm and at the same time have each new run using different input data ... thats like **a huge waste of time**.

Comment: Code is almost without any issue. But you may end up ArrayIndexOutOfBound. your condition in for loop should be `for (int w=0; w<x.length-2; w++)`

Comment: what are the resultant numbers you got so far?

Comment: My code doesnt seem to be finding all combinations. I was checking manualy by using ctrl f in txt file. The solution below with regex, seems to be working great.  Thank You guyz.

Answer (score 0):

If you convert the "rows" of your 2d array from char[] to string then you do not need to handle the matching yourself. Two possibilities to find out the number of occurences of "ala":

first using regex

```
public static void main (String []args){

    char[][] x = new char[10][11]; 

    int amountofAlaTotal = 0;
    String abc = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    for (int i=0; i<x.length; i++) {
        for (int r=0; r<x[i].length; r++)  {
            x[i][r] = abc.charAt((int)(Math.random()*26)) ;
        }
    }         
    for (int i=0; i<x.length; i++) {            
        String str = String.valueOf(x[i]); //convert a char array to a string
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("ala");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
        int amountofAlaPerLine = 0;
        while (m.find()){
            amountofAlaPerLine +=1;
        }

        if(amountofAlaPerLine>0){
            System.out.println("str: "+str );
            System.out.println("index: " + i );
            System.out.println("matches: "+amountofAlaPerLine);
        }
        amountofAlaTotal += amountofAlaPerLine;

    }
    System.out.println("total: "+amountofAlaTotal );
}
```

or second using StringUtils.countMatches from Apache Commons Lang

```
public static void main (String []args){

    char[][] x = new char[10][11]; 
    int amountofAlaPerLine = 0;
    int amountofAlaTotal = 0;
    String abc = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    for (int i=0; i<x.length; i++) {
        for (int r=0; r<x[i].length; r++)  {
            x[i][r] = abc.charAt((int)(Math.random()*26)) ;
        }
    }         
    for (int i=0; i<x.length; i++) {            
        String str = String.valueOf(x[i]); //convert a char array to a string
        amountofAlaPerLine = StringUtils.countMatches(str, "ala"); //count matches
        if(amountofAlaPerLine>0){
            System.out.println("str: "+str );
            System.out.println("index: " + i );
            System.out.println("matches: "+amountofAlaPerLine);
        }
        amountofAlaTotal += amountofAlaPerLine;

    }
    System.out.println("total: "+amountofAlaTotal );
}
```